# Open Graph & Rails not retrieving object's URL

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-opengraph, koala

I'm using Rails to try and add an action for an object both defined for my app on the open graph. I am using an :after_filter in my controller to call the following after session#create:

```
@graph.put_connections('me', 'workkout:complete', :session => url_for([@plan, @session]))
```

I am getting the following back from Facebook:

```
{"error":{"type":"Exception","message":"Could not retrieve data from URL.","code":1660002}}
```

I have checked that the correct URL is passed to put_connections, and when I visit this URL using Facebook's Lint tool, everything is correct.

I can't understand why this isn't working, my only thought is that Facebook is hitting the URL moments before rails has generated the object? - not sure if that's even possible though.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I tried passing a fixed string as the URL and this works, so it must be that facebook hits the url before the model is created.. I'm doing this within if @session.save - yet it still doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Are you running this in production? Do you have an example URL that Facebook has trouble with?

Comment: This is an example of what I'm sending, it looks fine in the lint tool - http://workkout.herokuapp.com/plans/1/sessions/18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because the create action and the put_connection methods take place in independent threads and as such the URL is not ready when put_connections is called. Solution here http://railscasts.com/episodes/363-facebook-open-graph?autoplay=true

Comment: Oh no, that link is behind a paywall! Care to summarize for poor folks like me with this exact issue but no interest in a railscasts subscription?